# Does Reverse proxy in IIS effects SEO in any way

Tags: seo, google-search-console, web-crawlers, iis, node-js

I'm creating a website using Angular and have enabled server-side rendering which uses a Node JS server.

Our site is deployed on an IIS server. To get content from the Node server we are using a reverse proxy (Application Request Routing- AAR). Will this affect SEO in any way?

To my knowledge, it is not a 302 redirect so all the Ranking and traffic juice will not get affected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reverse proxy should be entirely invisible to the user, so no, it should not in any way affect SEO.

If, however, the (remote) server you were proxying to was slow or on a slow connection then yes, that could affect SEO, simply because it would slow everything down. But that does not seem to be the case here.

Comment: 100% agree with this answer.  I just want to add that using a reverse proxy to another port on the same machine or to another machine on a local network is a very common setup that rarely introduces performance problems bad enough to hurt SEO.  Reverse proxies can even improve performance in some cases by distributing load onto different servers in a local network.